# When 'no results' return from a query show some default results

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

if no result found, need to show some default value for single row
and multiple column for example query

```
select CASE 
         WHEN entity_id IS NULL  THEN 0 ELSE entity_id  
       END simplefiled  
from tds2022.quarter_main
where client_id = 6365;
```

above query  not working when no records exists

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: am expecting result 0 as output, for the column simplefiled

Comment: So there is no row where client_id = 6365, but you want to show a result anyway?

Comment: Well, if the WHERE clause doesn't return any row, then you can't have any values for the column.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, am using postgresSql-11 ,

Comment: if there is nothing, then query cannot return any thing. You can use plpgsql(https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS)    control structure to force it return something.